# Getting "undefined" value when calling "getServerSideProps" function in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

Getting an "undefined" value when calling the `getServerSideProps` function in Next.js 13

Like this:

> Data is: undefined

Error: When I go to console the data in default export it shows an undefined

```
export default async function page({data}) {
console.log("Data is: "+data);

return (
<h1>`Test page`</h1>
)
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
const response = await fetch("``https://dummyjson.com/users``");
const data = await response.json();
return {
props: {data},
}
}
```

I want us to get an object that has an array name `users` which contains the user's data.

That's all I want.

Comment: Maybe the problem is connected to url, I think it contains too many backticks, just try to paste url like this:  `fetch("https://dummyjson.com/users")`